# How to convert HttpPostedFileBase to TextReader for CsvHelper library

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm trying to process a user uploaded CSV file using the `CsvHelper` library. I'm not sure how to get the `HttpPostedFileBase` file that the user uploads converted to the `TextReader reader` format that the `CsvReader` requires? Here is what I have so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fileContents = new StreamReader(file).ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

        //using CsvHelper Library
        var csv = new CsvReader(fileContents);
        var model = csv.GetRecords<BattingStats>().ToList();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!